# How to debug a class file in eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Since a long time i have been searching how to debug a class file in Java.

For example :- consider a below code snipet.

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("1","A");
map.put("2","B");
```

Now when if i want to understand internal working of put then it should redirect me to put method in HashMap class.
I have installed decompiler in my eclipse.
I set the breakpoint over put() but compiler does not comes till this point.
It skips the internal working of the method and points directly to next line defined by me.

Please help if there is anyway to debug class file

Answer (score 1):

To debug the execution of core/JDK classes with breakpoints you need to add the source code of these classes.
For recent versions of Java, after unpackaging/installing the JDK, 
you will find an archive at the root of the JDK folder such as src.zip for a Windows JDK.

Once you identified this file, make it accessible in any Eclipse projects by configuring the sources in the installed JRE section of the Eclipse preferences :

- select the JRE (JDK generally) that you are using
- click on "Edit"
- select all JRE system libraries and click on "Source Attachement"
- click on "External File" to select the zip file containing the sources you previously downloaded.
- valid it by clicking "OK"

Here is a screenshot capturing relevant information :

[image]

Comment: Hi,Thanx for your answer but no luck so far

Comment: Hi Davidxxx,Got the success.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the setup posted by davidxxx When in debug mode and the execution hits your debug point remember to use "step into" rather than "step over". "step into" will then get you into the .put() method.

Comment: That is self understood.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a decompiler for this, not for classes in the JDK. Trying to use one might even cause you problems.  Usually all you have to do is make sure your Installed JREs preference page contains a JDK and that you launch your Java Application using it, and not a JRE. The location of a JDK's sources are well known, so should be found automatically, and a JDK's .class files contain the debugging information to expose field names and local variables to the debugger while stepping.